# Show that if $j:[0,t]\to [0,t]$ is continuous on $[0,t]$ and then there exists $x^{**}\in [0,t]$ such that $j(x^{**})=x^{**}$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $h:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $\{h(x)\space|\space x\in [0,1]\} \subseteq [0,1]$ then there exists $x^* \in [0,1]$ such that $h(x^*)= x^*$.

Let $t>0$. Using only the following results,

1. Let $X, Y \subseteq \mathbb{R.}\space$For $f:X \to \mathbb{R}, g:Y\to\mathbb{R}\space$with $\{f(x)\space|\space x\in X\}\subseteq Y.\space$If $f$ is continuous at $c\in X$ and $g$ is continuous at $f(c)$ then $g\circ f:X\to\mathbb{R}\space$is continuous on X.
2. Let $a>0.\space$Then $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\space$given by $f(x)=ax$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}.$

show that if $j:[0,t]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[0,t]$ and  $\{j(x)\space|\space x\in [0,t]\}\subseteq [0,t]$ then there exists $x^{**}\in [0,t]$ such that $j(x^{**})=x^{**}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the curve $f:[0,t]\to[0,1]$ given by $f(x)=\frac{x}{t}$. Note by 2. we have $f(x)=\frac{x}{t}=\frac{1}{t}.x$ is continuous since $\frac{1}{t}>0.$

Then by 1. we have $h\circ f$ is continuous on $[0,t]$

The composition of functions $t\circ h\circ f(x)$ where $t:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $t(x)=tx$ maps the range from $[0,1]\to[0,t].$ And we know this is continuous since this is the composition of the continous functions and $t$ is continuous by 2.

Thus define $j:[0,t]\to[0,t]$ by $t\circ h\circ f:[0,t]\to[0,t].$

Now for $x^{*}\in [0,1]$ such that $h(x^{*})=x^{*},$ choose $x^{**}=tx^{*}\in [0,t],$ which gives us:

$$j(x^{**})=j(tx^{*})=t\circ h\circ f(tx^{*})=t\circ h(x^{*})=t(x^{*})=tx^{*}=x^{**}$$
as required.